# Web API Controller POST Request LINQ search through String Array

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have the following database structure.

[image: structure]

Sorry for the horrible MS Paint Work

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 Web API Controller using Entity Framework.

My API Controller handles a post request that receives a structure similar to:

```
{  "countryCode": "CA", "languageCode": "EN ","partTypes": "Brakes", "partComponents": "Relay" }
```

^^ Above request should find Part ID = 1 , and I want to select Part Request URL

```
{ "countryCode": "US","languageCode": "EN ","partTypes": " Brakes , Clutch", "partComponents": "Relay"}
```

^^ Above request should find Part ID = 1 & 2 , and I want to select Part Request URL for both.

“Clutch, Resistor, EN, US” Should find Part ID = 2 etc.

My Question is how am I able to use LINQ to SQL or `<IQueryable>` to return the part ID for whatever post request is captured by the controller. 
The current code I have been working on so far looks similar to this:

Inside API Controller:

```
public string Post(PostProfile postProfile) 
string[] partURLArray;
{
using (var context = new context())
{partURLArray = context.ViewName
.Where(fields = > field.CountryCode.Contains(postProfile.countryCode)
.Where(fields => fields.LanguageCode.Contains(postProfile.languageCode)
.Select(fields => fields.PartRequestURL).ToArray();
}
foreach 
(var part in partURLArray)
{
//do some stuff
}
return partString
}
```

Post Profile Model Class:

```
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string languageCode { get; set; }
    public string[] partType { get; set; }
    public string[] partComponents { get; set; }
```

Comment: you mean something like this?  `fields => postProfile.partType.Contains(fields.PartType)`

Answer (score 0):

You answer isn't clear for and I cannot fully understand what you are want to do.
As I understand you want to return Part1 and Part2 urls in one Query. If is true.Got it

```
 using (var context = new context())
 {partURLArray = context.ViewName
 .Where(fields = > field.CountryCode.Contains(postProfile.countryCode)
  OR fields.LanguageCode.Contains(postProfile.languageCode)
 .Select(fields => fields.PartRequestURL).ToArray();
```